# How do you create an AWS IAM policy that allows, or denies, based on a specific time of day, but not a date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, amazon-iam, policy

The [AWS reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) shows how to allow, or deny, based on a Date and time:

```
"Condition": {
  "DateGreaterThan" : {
     "aws:CurrentTime" : "2013-12-15T12:00:00Z"
   }
}
```

We want to restrict access to a specific time of day, without specifying a specific day. There aren't any Time operators, such as TimeGreaterThan, which would allow something like

```
"Condition": {
  "TimeGreaterThan" : {
     "aws:CurrentTime" : "05:00:00Z"
   },
  "TimeLessThan" : {
     "aws:CurrentTime" : "06:00:00Z"
   }
}
```

Is there a way to use wildcards?

```
"Condition": {
  "DateGreaterThan" : {
     "aws:CurrentTime" : "*T05:00:00Z"
   },
  "DateGreaterThan" : {
     "aws:CurrentTime" : "*T06:00:00Z"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is an option, but a workaround could be using a CloudWatch Event that triggers a lambda that modifies the policy once a day. Not a perfect option but it should work and if you have to change it everyday then this method might be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible, however you can use the aws CLI in order to run a script each day that updates the policy (I know it's bit ugly but it works)

Let's assume that the policy ARN is `arn:aws:iam::1234:policy/my-policy` (The policy ARN is viewed in the policy edit page)

Execute the next script [aws cli command](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

`aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::1234:policy/my-policy --version-id v2`

It should return something like:

```
 "PolicyVersion": {
     "CreateDate": "2016-09-28T13:04:09Z",
     "VersionId": "v2",
     "Document": {
         "Version": "2012-10-17",
         "Statement": [
             {
                 "Action": "*",
                 "Resource": "*",
                 "Effect": "Allow",
                 "Sid": "...",
                 "condition" : //your time condition
             }
         ]
     },
     "IsDefaultVersion": true
 }
```

This was made to be sure that you are on the right ARN, now we can also modify this policy

Write a script that dynamically generates the json file with the required time, see **example1** for a nodejs code example:

Then you just have to execute the next command:
`aws iam create-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::1234:policy/my-policy --policy-document file://path_to_generated_json.json --set-as-default`

And you actually updated the policy for today!

Make a service that run this every day

**Example 1**:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const dateBegin = new Date();
dateBegin.setHours(17);
dateBegin.setMinutes(0);
dateBegin.setSeconds(0);
dateBegin.setMilliseconds(0);

const dateEnd = new Date();
dateEnd.setHours(19);
dateEnd.setMinutes(0);
dateEnd.setSeconds(0);
dateEnd.setMilliseconds(0);

const policy = {
    "version" : "2012-10-17",
    "statement" : [
        {
            "condition" : {
                "DateGreaterThan" : {
                    "aws:CurrentTime" : dateBegin.toISOString()
                },
                "DateLessThan" : {
                    "aws:CurrentTime" : dateEnd.toISOString()
                },
                "allow" : "..."
            }
        }
    ]
}

fs.writeFileSync("path_to_file.json",JSON.stringify(policy))

//File Output:
{
  "version": "2012-10-17",
  "statement": [
    {
      "condition": {
        "DateGreaterThan": {
          "aws:CurrentTime": "2017-01-27T15:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "DateLessThan": {
          "aws:CurrentTime": "2017-01-27T17:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "allow": "..."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```